# How I create application file like .apk for Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, xap

I'm developing Windows Phone application.I'm finished.I need application file.How I create application file like .apk for Windows Phone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.apk file is an Android file which contain whole application. For Windows Phone 7 equivalent is .xap file. This is just a zip file with the app and resources. Just remember to upload the release one from `Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\AppName\Bin\Release\`.

Comment: Do I should zip my release folder ? It contains, dll files,xap file,xml files etc.I wanted to send application,do I should send zip file ?

Comment: The .xap file is the full application. Just like Android's .apk.

Comment: @J.S.D.M it's already done for you. Change the extension to .zip and you will see what's inside.

Answer (score 2):

When you build your project you should get a *.xap* file somewhere in your projects directory.
I have not worked with Windows Phone myself, so i do not know exactly where. But if it is like desktop C#, the default is bin/release, or bin/debug if it's a debug build.